# Finding text in json with python

Tags: python, json

I've got a json file that I'm importing into Python and trying to look for the occurrence of a phrase. If I try this:

```
any(keyword in s for s in json_data)
```

where keyword is the thing I'm looking for and json_data is what I got from using json.load(). It always returns false even when the keyword is in json_data. Here's how I'm indexing into the json:

```
json_data["thing1"]["thing2"][0]["thing3"]
```

The field [0] varies from 0-16 and the thing I want is in thing3. Why can't I get a True even when the keyword is in json_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
any(keyword in s for s in json_data)
```

is looking in the first level dictionary, where `thing1` is located. You have to look at the dictionary containing `thing3`, which is the indexed one

```
any(keyword in s for s in json_data["thing1"]["thing2"])
```

Assuming `thing3` is the `keyword` you are looking for...

Comment: Well, there's one more part to it. Basically I'm trying to find a one-liner for looping through json_data["thing1"]["thing2"][0]["thing3"], then json_data["thing1"]["thing2"][1]["thing3"], etc where thing3 is the keyword.

Comment: Ok, change it to `any(keyword in s["thing3"] for s in json_data["thing1"]["thing2"])`